# Administrate with custom devise controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, thoughtbot

I'm using Administrate for the first time with Devise and have just generated some devise controllers in order to customize them and now [Administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) throws an error.

For each of the controllers i generated, it throws this error:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant AdminUsers::Session:
```

Stack trace:

```
    NameError - uninitialized constant AdminUsers::Session:
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:533:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
  administrate (0.2.2) app/helpers/administrate/application_helper.rb:12:in `display_resource_name'
  app/views/admin/application/_sidebar.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_admin_application__sidebar_html_erb___259992220382990803_70276796335240'
  app/views/admin/application/_sidebar.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_admin_application__sidebar_html_erb___259992220382990803_70276796335240'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:51:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
  app/views/layouts/admin/application.html.erb:31:in `_app_views_layouts_admin_application_html_erb__4415338589856147193_70276819419860'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/jamesrobinson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  searchkick (1.3.4) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:158:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  administrate (0.2.2) app/controllers/administrate/application_controller.rb:12:in `index'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  searchkick (1.3.4) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:153:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/jamesrobinson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
  /Users/jamesrobinson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
  /Users/jamesrobinson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :admin_users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'admin_users/sessions',
    confirmations: 'admin_users/confirmations',
    registrations: 'admin_users/registrations',
    passwords: 'admin_users/passwords',
    unlocks: 'admin_users/unlocks',
  }

  namespace :admin do
    resources :admin_users
    resources :users
    resources :bookings
    resources :locations
    resources :tournaments
    resources :players
    resources :images
    root to: "tournaments#index"
  end

end
```

Does anyone know what the solution is for this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue on Rails 5.0.1 with administrate and devise.
It turns out that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/758) as of administrate@0.3.0 regarding namespace handling.

If you don't want to wait for the new release with fix, here's a workaround for avoiding this issue:

It's simple. All you need to do is just use another namespace other than string that starts with `"admin"`. E.g. you can change it like the following and the issue will be gone.

```
devise_for :admin_users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'admeen_users/sessions',
  ...
}

class AdmeenUsers::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  ...
end
```

**P.S.** If you want to authenticate administrate with AdminUser model, you need to wrap the `namespace :admin do ... end` part with `authenticate :admin_user do ... end`.